# Hierarchical Representation using outline grouping in Excel

Tags: excel, macros, vba

**I have table as shown below:-**

[image: Dummy Table]

Using the above table I want to show an hierarchical representation using outline grouping. Also data should be shown with subtotal or any other custom operation in next following columns as follows.

[image: Result]

- Is there any operation in excel to represent this structure?
- Should I have to write a macro to show this representation and related calculation?
- I have to show more custom calculation`(e.g: $B23*3 in column C along with subtotal on its upper tree node )` in next columns apart from count functionality for that represented data. The count and its subtotal is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a Pivot-Table with your values.
[image: Representation of the Pivot-Data]

Comment: Yup, thats it, i did exactly the same!

Comment: Yes i can use Pivot table but can I do custom calculation along with its subtotals in next 5 columns as mentioned in my Question?   That one subtotal column was just an example. There are many custom calculation I have to show for that represented data.

Comment: As long as the data is in your table you can calculated with the columns. If there are realy special operations, it can be useful to use a help step in a column.. (intermediate result? is it the right translation)

Comment: Sorry did not get you. Can you elaborate? It would be help full. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dan H's got it and real quick at that, all credits to him, I'm just posting to show how this is the one way you think of it if you work with excel:

[image: the original data (in an excel table) and the pivot]